# How to align table header and textarea's content

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment, textarea

Is it possible to align **textarea's content** with **table's header**? I tried `&nbsp;` but it's not good for responsive design, any suggestions?

Update, expected output:
[image]

```html
<tbody>
<tr>
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Number</th> 
  <th>Line</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td colspan="3" align="center">
    <textarea id="log" wrap="hard" readonly="1" style="width:100%; height:100px; resize: none;">
Jan  1 00:00:31     111     line 5
Jan  1 00:00:45     111     line 10 
Jan  1 00:00:08     222     line 2 
Jan  1 00:00:31     333     line 111
Jan  1 00:00:45     333     line 20 
    </textarea>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: How will you expecting, while responsive td.??

Comment: Sorry I removed td.

Comment: what you want to do explain brief

Comment: your expected output..??

Comment: I want to align th's "D" to texarea's "J", th's "N" to number's "1" and th's ''L" to textarea's "line"

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier not to use a textarea at all:

```
<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Number</th>
    <th>Line</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> Jan  1 00:00:31 </td>
    <td> 111 </td>
    <td> line 5 </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, but that's not what I'm looking for. Actually I can do very well if I use td, but I'm looking for any possible while using textarea cause sometimes log file's information can be very big.